# Automate steps to import to MS Access and macro

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, automation, build-automation

I have 1000+ XML files which need to be run through an MS Access database.

The process just now is:

- Import single XML to MS Access
- Run macro
- Data is written to a table
- Start again

This was fine when I was dealing with tens of files per week, but now it has risen and will only continue.

Any ideas on how I could automate this process would be very helpful.

Comment: So is each xml file an insert query or something?

Comment: the macro runs a few queries, against the data in the xml file and writes the answers to a table.

Comment: Please give an example of how these XML files look like, and a sample of you code. Do they have an identical schema?

Comment: They have an identical schema, they are large detailed xml's. I have no code, I just import them one at a time manually just now and run the marco everytime I import one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

1) Find a procedure to combine all the XML files, given they are the same. See this thread for some ideas --> [Combining multiple xml documents into one large one with a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377949/combining-multiple-xml-documents-into-one-large-one-with-a-batch-file)

2) Run Macro

3) Write data to table